# Laravel Forge (Nginx) Gzip and browser caching + SSL

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, laravel-forge

I'm trying to improve the browser caching as well as using gzip compression. 
Within my investigations I came across sources saying that you should not enable compression when SSL is enabled.

I came across this  nginx settings for my setup. 
https://gist.github.com/reedmaniac/adfa2740323d08de25bd

Could anyone advise whether I can follow the above setting blindly, or I need to leave the default Forge setting?

Here is the the google developer page speed result on my website which indicating I need to leverage browser caching and compression:
https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.itutorialist.com

Comment: *Within my investigations I came across sources saying that you should not enable compression when SSL is enabled.* - this is not completely wrong but far from correct. You should not enable compression for content which can have secrets (like CSRF tokens) but it is fine to have compression enabled for non-sensitive content. For details see https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/20406/is-http-compression-safe.  This also means that your config which enables gzip might be a problem or might be not, depending on your content. Apart from that this is unrelated to caching.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. Given I have SSL setup on my website is there any easy/standard way of Nginx setup to improve compression and caching so I wouldn't be the victim of BREACH/CRIME attacks? Sorry I don't have enough knowledge in this area and still digging to find out more.

Comment: This is not specific to nginx. It depends on your application, i.e. which parts contain sensitive data and which parts not. If nothing in your applications contains sensitive data then you can compress everything.

Answer (score 2):

here is my setting in nginx.conf forge inside serve

```
# browser caching of static assets
    location ~*  \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js|pdf)$ {
        expires 7d;
    }

    server_tokens off;

    #GZIP
    # Enable gzip compression.
    gzip on;

    # Compression level (1-9).
    # 5 is a perfect compromise between size and CPU usage, offering about
    # 75% reduction for most ASCII files (almost identical to level 9).
    gzip_comp_level    5;

    # Don't compress anything that's already small and unlikely to shrink much
    # if at all (the default is 20 bytes, which is bad as that usually leads to
    # larger files after gzipping).
    gzip_min_length    256;

    # Compress data even for clients that are connecting to us via proxies,
    # identified by the "Via" header (required for CloudFront).
    gzip_proxied       any;

    # Tell proxies to cache both the gzipped and regular version of a resource
    # whenever the client's Accept-Encoding capabilities header varies;
    # Avoids the issue where a non-gzip capable client (which is extremely rare
    # today) would display gibberish if their proxy gave them the gzipped version.
    gzip_vary          on;

    # Compress all output labeled with one of the following MIME-types.
    gzip_types
      application/atom+xml
      application/javascript
      application/json
      application/ld+json
      application/manifest+json
      application/rss+xml
      application/vnd.geo+json
      application/vnd.ms-fontobject
      application/x-font-ttf
      application/x-web-app-manifest+json
      application/xhtml+xml
      application/xml
      font/opentype
      image/bmp
      image/svg+xml
      image/x-icon
      text/cache-manifest
      text/css
      text/plain
      text/vcard
      text/vnd.rim.location.xloc
      text/vtt
      text/x-component
      text/x-cross-domain-policy;
```

Hope this is will be helpful to everyone

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have GZIP configured correctly. Your current issue is that you are not [setting an appropriate Cache-Control header](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/LeverageBrowserCaching), and that your images are very poorly [optimised](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/OptimizeImages).

Comment: Thanks for your guidance I'll go through links you shared to setup the appropriate cache-control header. I don't have good knowledge for Nginx configurations. Is it a general setting that I need to follow for cache-control header in the Nginx config or it's varied case to case? To my understanding not everything should be cached blindly which can cause some vulnerabilities